# Distance between two points on the Moon

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, trigonometry

Given latitude/longitude of two points on the Moon `(lat1, lon1)` and `(lat2, lon2)`, compute the distance between the two points in kilometers, by using **any formula** that gives the same result as the haversine formula.

### Input

- Four integer values `lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2` in degree (angle) or
- four decimal values `ϕ1, λ1, ϕ2, λ2` in radians.

### Output

Distance in kilometers between the two points (decimal with any precision or rounded integer).

### Haversine formula

[image: d = 2 r \arcsin\left(\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{\phi_2 - \phi_1}{2}\right) + \cos(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2)\sin^2\left(\frac{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}{2}\right)}\right)]

where

- `r` is the radius of the sphere (assume that the Moon's radius is 1737 km),
- `ϕ1` latitude of point 1 in radians
- `ϕ2` latitude of point 2 in radians
- `λ1` longitude of point 1 in radians
- `λ2` longitude of point 2 in radians
- `d` is the circular distance between the two points

(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

### Other possible formulas

- `d = r * acos(sin ϕ1 sin ϕ2 + cos ϕ1 cos ϕ2 cos(λ2 - λ1))` [*@miles*'  formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon#comment391848_161789).
- `d = r * acos(cos(ϕ1 - ϕ2) + cos ϕ1 cos ϕ2 (cos(λ2 - λ1) - 1))` [*@Neil*'s  formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon/161802#comment391978_161802).

### Example where inputs are degrees and output as rounded integer

```
42, 9, 50, 2  --> 284
50, 2, 42, 9  --> 284
4, -2, -2, 1  --> 203
77, 8, 77, 8  --> 0
10, 2, 88, 9  --> 2365
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Specify in the answer whether the inputs are in **degrees** or **radians**.
- No need to handle **invalid latitude/longitude values**
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Using that particular formula is an unobservable requirement. Isn't it enough to give the same result as that formula *would* give?

Comment: May we take the input in radians?

Comment: Must we round, or may we return a result with decimals?

Comment: @Adám the inputs are in degree to avoid decimal inputs

Comment: @Adám decimal with any precision or rounded integer

Comment: @Adám yes of-course, you are allowed to use any formula that gives the same result.

Comment: @mdahmoune OK, so you listed in degrees for ease of writing, but *may* we require input to be in radians? Otherwise this challenge becomes a combo (which is bad) of angle conversion and of the main challenge.

Comment: @mdahmoune If any formula is allowed, you should state so.

Comment: *`ϕ1` latitude of point 1 in radians*: since the only way the angles are used are as arguments to `sin`, their unit doesn't matter.

Comment: @Adám you can use degrees or radian just specify in the answer whether the inputs are in degrees or radian.

Comment: I don't think this challenge will prompt varied or interesting answers. When the method of solving it is the same, you get a bunch of cookie-cutter solutions.

Comment: @mbomb007 Who says the method must be the same... | {@}mdahmoune are you still going to keep that **unobservable** requirement? What if our language doesn't have sine and only cosine? Can we use cosine and shift the values instead? etc.

Comment: @user202729 it is mentioned in the question that you can use any formula that gives the same result as the haversine formula.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it seems more to be 'Who's language can golf this formula the most', which, in my opinion, isn't particularly interesting.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Of course you can use another formula...

Comment: A shorter formula for most languages would be `d = r * acos( sin ϕ1 sin ϕ2 + cos ϕ1 cos ϕ2 cos(λ2 - λ1) )` where `r = 1737`

Comment: @miles thanks you can update the question by adding your formula if you want

Comment: @miles `r * acos(cos(ϕ1 - ϕ2) + cos ϕ1 cos ϕ2 (cos(λ2 - λ1) - 1))` is shorter still in some languages.

Comment: I agree that Neil's and miles' formulas are mathematically equivalent, but the haversine formula was intended to give better precision in the cases the angles are close to each other.

Comment: Are we supposed to pretend that the Moon is spherical?  It's less oblate than Earth, but still seems wrong to simplify that much...

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, at least for this challenge

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes

```
ArcCos[Sin@#*Sin@#3+Cos[#2-#4]Cos@#*Cos@#3]1737&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb89@xKNk5vzg6ODPPQVkLTBprgwSUjXSVTWKBLKAwmDSONTQ3Nlf7nxZtYqTgkppelJqqo2AJZ5kawJkw6VgFfX0FPxARUJSZV/IfAA)

Uses the formula `d = r * acos( sin ϕ1 sin ϕ2 + cos ϕ1 cos ϕ2 cos(λ2 - λ1) )` where `r = 1737`

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [geosphere](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/), <s>54</s> 47 bytes

```r
function(p,q)geosphere::distHaversine(p,q,1737)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NAp1AzPTW/uCAjtSjVyiols7jEI7Estag4My8VJKljaG5srvk/TSNZw1LHxEhTJ1nDSMfUQFPzPwA)

Takes input as 2-element vectors of `longitude,latitude` in degrees. TIO doesn't have the `geosphere` package but rest assured that it returns identical results to the function below.

Thanks to Jonathan Allan for shaving off 7 bytes.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
function(p,l,q,k)1737*acos(sin(p)*sin(q)+cos(p)*cos(q)*cos(k-l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfrmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NAJ0enUCdb09Dc2FwrMTm/WKM4EyiqqQWiCjW1QSJAHogqhFDZujmamv/TNUyMtAoy9Q0tDHQsYQxTAxgLJqf5HwA)

Takes 4 inputs as in the test cases, but in radians rather than degrees.

Comment: Are the `e3` and `/1000` really necessary?

Comment: @JonathanAllan no they are not. That's pretty dumb of me, but the default argument for the radius is the earth's in meters so it was logical at the time, lol

Comment: Note that the spherical law of cosines is not numerically stable, in particular for small distances. That's probably ok [in Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161824/2183), but in R and most other languages it's debatable whether the "any formula that gives the same result as the haversine formula" criterion is fulfilled.

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis I mostly included it for the sake of having it in base R. I suppose using an arbitrary precision floating point library would mitigate the effect.

Comment: Yes, or using a stable formula like, say, the haversine formula...

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>40</s> 35 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit function. Takes {ϕ₁,λ₁} as left argument and {ϕ₂,λ₂} as right argument.

Uses the formula 2 r √(sin²(<sup>(ϕ₁-ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) + cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂ sin²(<sup>(λ₁ – λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>))

```apl
3474×¯1○.5*⍨1⊥(×⍨1○2÷⍨-)×1,2×.○∘⊃,¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxCoMwFMbxvad4oykqvjSSeBwh0EVocetcKKIU3J4XKLg5dk9ukoukj9hCtz8/Pr722hX21naXc4w2POaT0sqT2zDQVNbH8FwxjK/MUyqapH9zFcIT5tJTyRSGJYz33K2x5wMGngwLmipmPSgJ0AiwwF1XIMVhD64dedAkBAVu@ykXYGKtAcxXuU1C/Dswhg8@) (the `r` function converts degrees to radians)

---

`,¨` concatenate corresponding elements; {{ϕ₁ , ϕ₂} , {λ₁ , λ₂}}

`⊃` pick the first; {ϕ₁ , ϕ₂}

`∘` then

`2×.○` product of their cosines; cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂
 <sup>lit. dot "product" but with trig function selector (2 is cosine) instead of multiplication and times instead of plus</sup>

`1,` prepend 1 to that; {1 , cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂}

`(`…`)×` multiply that by the result of applying following function to {ϕ₁ , λ₁} and {ϕ₂ , λ₂}:

`-` their differences; {ϕ₁ - ϕ₂ , λ₁ - λ₂}

`2÷⍨` divide that by 2; {<sup>(ϕ₁ - ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> , <sup>(λ₁ - λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>}

`1○` sine of that; {sin(<sup>(ϕ₁ - ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) , sin(<sup>(λ₁ - λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)}

`×⍨` square that (lit. self-multiply); {sin²(<sup>(ϕ₁ - ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) , sin²(<sup>(λ₁-λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)}

Now we have {sin²(<sup>(ϕ₁ - ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) , cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂ sin²(<sup>(λ₁ - λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)}

`1⊥` sum that (lit. evaluate in base-1); sin²(<sup>(ϕ₁-ϕ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) + cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂ sin²(<sup>(λ₁ - λ₂)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)

`.5*⍨` square-root of that (lit. raise that to the power of a half)

`¯1○` arcsine of that

`3474×` multiply that by this

---

The function to allow input in degrees is:

```apl
○÷∘180
```

`÷180` argument divided by 180

`○` multiply by π

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 90 bytes

*Note: see [@OlivierGrégoire's post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161862/58563) for a much shorter solution*

A direct port of [TFeld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161793/58563). Takes input in radians.

```javascript
(a,b,c,d,M=Math)=>3474*M.asin((M.sin((c-a)/2)**2+M.cos(c)*M.cos(a)*M.sin((d-b)/2)**2)**.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDBDoMgDIbvPAVHYIDKNLKDu@9AsldA1OliZBlmr8/U7SYHPDRt/vzt1/apP9qZ9/Ca2WSb1neVR5rW1NCGqkrpucfV9ZyXOVFcu2FCSPEtGaZxIjAh4qS4sQ4ZTH6FXovN07D671mCF9gbOzk7tny0D9QhAGEuIIErhd9vMIGZTOmiXmBILdKQKnZegDEAO1JsNz2w1UranxQcyUS8msWByjLULIP4WG8QlB14nZTRr/Nf)

## Using the infamous [`with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), 85 bytes

*Thanks to @l4m2 for saving 6 bytes*

```javascript
with(Math)f=(a,b,c,d)=>3474*asin((sin((c-a)/2)**2+cos(c)*cos(a)*sin((d-b)/2)**2)**.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZA7DoMwDIb3nCJjnCY8UhDpQPcOlXqFEKCAEKka1B4/BdSNDGGwLf1@fLYH9VFWv/vXzCdTN859@7kjdzV30JZEsYppVkN5PWdFRpXtJ0I2p7mCWACl4qSNJRroGhTQLVvz6p9dLMrBaTNZMzbRaJ6kJQjjTGCKV0z0uOEYpzJhi3rBPjVPfKrY1SIAhHak0G52YKuVtD/JO5KLcDUNAxWFr1l68aG1XlB64HVSBr/O/QA)

Comment: You can do `with(Math)f=(a,b,c,d)=>3474*asin((sin((c-a)/2)**2+cos(c)*cos(a)*sin((d-b)/2)**2)**.5)`

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZCxDsIgEIZ3noKRq4ClasCh7g4kvgKlrdY0xUjj66NonMpAtz9f7u67u7t5GW@fw2Nmk2u70NeBGNpQS1uqa23mG9QnIXey0NxY54nmfpiIgeIXLGw0j/xLYrD/0LIGIFg3eTd2fHRX0hOE8b7CBY6D@eWMt1iokn7oEafooUzRalGLABBamHK76Yqtoml5UnIkq/KpyBNJmWpWSX1ubVIkVrxOqezXhTc) using [*@miles*' shorter algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon#comment391848_161789): `(a,b,c,d,M=Math)=>1737*M.acos(M.sin(a)*M.sin(c)+M.cos(a)*M.cos(c)*M.cos(d-b))`

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZDLDsIgEEX3fMUsGQQsVQMu6t4Fib9AaX2lKcY2/j7a2F1Z0M1kcudxZu7Tfdzg34/XKPrQtPFaRep4zT1vuK2sG@9YnZTeaWal82GgVk7RCY@bOUX2TzyyudqIGoVCjD70Q@ha2YUbvVICsC@BwbRVXs6wBWUK/lOPkFIPRUotF70EkZAFKXear7hqIi1fSq4UZb6q8kBap4ZNEp/bmwSpFdYZk21d/AI) using [*@Neil*'s shorter algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon/161802#comment391978_161802): `(a,b,c,d,M=Math)=>1737*M.acos(M.cos(a-c)+M.cos(a)*M.cos(c)*(M.cos(d-b)-1))`

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZC/DsIgEId3nuJGDqGWqgGHunRyMPEVKP2jpinGNr4@Ytcy0OnCl/vdd9zLfM1kP8/3LEbXtL4rPTW85pY3vCpvZn5k1k1YXqQ6KLa8TQC0okZY3IWCrKIWWSCNqFFIRG/dOLmhzQbX044SgGMBDJbw/Qp7kDrngZ4hRk95jBarXoJIyMqUmuYbtvqb1l@KjhRFOpVpIqViYR3Vp/ZGRXLD6bROPp3/AQ) optimizing everybody's answer: `(a,b,c,d,C=Math.cos)=>1737*Math.acos(C(a-c)+C(a)*C(c)*(C(d-b)-1))`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Very nice. You probably should post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c,d,C=Math.cos)=>1737*Math.acos(C(a-c)+C(a)*C(c)*(C(d-b)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZC/DsIgEId3nuJGDqGWqgGHunRyMPEVKP2jpinGNr4@Ytcy0OnCl/vdd9zLfM1kP8/3LEbXtL4rPTW85pY3vCpvZn5k1k1YXqQ6KLa8TQC0okZY3IWCrKIWWSCNqFFIRG/dOLmhzQbX044SgGMBDJbw/Qp7kDrngZ4hRk95jBarXoJIyMqUmuYbtvqb1l@KjhRFOpVpIqViYR3Vp/ZGRXLD6bROPp3/AQ)

Based on Kevin Cruijssen's answer, Miles' and Neil's comments, and upon request of Arnauld.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 95 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:3474*asin((sin((c-a)/2)**2+cos(c)*cos(a)*sin((d-b)/2)**2)**.5)
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3NDoIwEITvPMUe27oolCJo4pt4WWgITexPoBefHrEYTxIPM3OYbzLhGUfv5DLc7suDbKcJCDvsUV8r1ShBs3GMJetz4ifJhZCH3s@s5@IdxEVqdd592lXHmmfD5C1YiiMYG/wUxRIm4yIMTFgKbCJtyM3IlES4INQFguScr96q7DeaGIS0@IMqhFxuKje0qHbQpkFoEVIktNgBy@2@bb/31bleXg)

Takes input in radians.

---

Old version, before i/o was slacked:
Takes input as integer degrees, and returns rounded dist

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 135 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:int(round(3474*asin((sin((r(c)-r(a))/2)**2+cos(r(c))*cos(r(a))*sin((r(d)-r(b))/2)**2)**.5)))
from math import*
r=radians
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29DoMwDIR3nsJjnJoWQii0Em/SJRAhkEqCAh369DSEn6HD2dZ9p/P4nTtrxNJWr@WthlorUFRTQ/rZm5k5@zGaZbKQXE29YSwMxxqMHVOIN4Gci0tjp2Ai3y5P@J7Ua7I@kl7XHBGj1tkBBjV30A@jdTOPXOWU7pWZltH519AyKQgeBHlCINCrlNGBgkcQEn9IEsRiU7qiJDtRURCUBGF5lJwg3erKcq/L7vnyAw)

Comment: you can drop `int` and `round` because decimals are allowed as output, you can also avoid conversion to radians because inputs as radians are also allowed

Comment: @mdahmoune, Thanks, updated

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>55</s> 50 bytes

```js
MsU *MsW +McU *McW *McX-V
ToMP1/7l¹ñ@McX aUÃv *#­7
```

Not necessarily quite as precise as the other answers, but boy did I have fun with this one. Allow me to elaborate.
While in most languages, this challenge is quite straightforward, Japt has the unfortunate property that there is no built-in for neither arcsine nor arccosine. Sure, you can embed Javascript in Japt, but that would be what ever the opposite of Feng Shui is.

All we have to do to overcome this minor nuisance is [approximate arccosine](https://www.karltarvas.com/2018/04/10/japt-approximating-arccos.html) and we're good to go!

The first part is everything that gets fed into the arccosine.

```js
MsU *MsW +McU *McW *McX-V
MsU                        // Take the sine of the first input and
    *MsW...                // multiply by the cos of the second one etc.
```

The result is implicitly stored in `U` to be used later.

Following that, we need to find a good approximation for arccosine. Since I'm lazy and not that good with math, we're obviously just going to brute-force it.

```js
ToMP1/7l¹ñ@McX aUÃv *#­7
T                       // Take 0
 o                      // and create a range from it
  MP                    // to π
    1/7l¹               // with resolution 1/7!.
         ñ@             // Sort this range so that
           McX          // the cosine of a given value
               aU       // is closest to U, e.g. the whole trig lot
                        // we want to take arccosine of.
                 Ã      // When that's done,
                  v     // get the first element
                    *#­7 // and multiply it by 1737, returning implicitly.
```

We could've used any large number for the generator resolution, manual testing showed `7!` is sufficiently large while being reasonably fast.

Takes input as radians, outputs unrounded numbers.

Shaved off five bytes thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/37c4VEHLtzhcQds3GcRKDgcREbphXCH5vgGG@uY5h3Ye3ugAFFJIDD3cXKagpXxorfn//wZ6BmaWFobGhuYGBuaW5ubGhhZcukBBYxNLAzNTC1MDY0sLCzNTS@yCQDFDcxNTYyNLI1NDS0sTIMMUAA)

Comment: You can remove the `(` in `Mc(X-V`. Since the char-code for `1737` isn't ISO-8859-1, it switches to UTF-8, which costs more. You can instead use the char-code for `173`+`7`. https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I603&input=

Comment: You can also remove the `,` after `ToMP` :-)

Comment: @Oliver Thanks a lot, the parenthesis were necessary in my original version but became obsolete when golfing it around a bit, I completely missed it though. Also, didn't know about the encoding thing, thanks a lot for that, too.

Comment: If you do want to go the JavaScript route, keep in mind that you can run everything through shoco.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>113</s> <s>92</s> <s>88</s> 82 bytes

```java
(a,b,c,d)->1737*Math.acos(Math.cos(a-c)+Math.cos(a)*Math.cos(c)*(Math.cos(d-b)-1))
```

Inputs `a,b,c,d` are `ϕ1,λ1,ϕ2,λ2` in radians.

-21 bytes using [*@miles*' shorter formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon#comment391848_161789).
-4 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégore* because I still used `{Math m=null;return ...;}` with every `Math.` as `m.`, instead of dropping the `return` and use `Math` directly.
-6 bytes using [*@Neil*'s shorter formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon/161802#comment391978_161802).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVBBTsMwELzzij3aYR2aUJSgCu4cWiH1iDhsbAMpqVPVbiWE@vZgJy5NbpVsa2a9q5nZDR1JbNR3JxuyFpZUm98bgNo4vf8gqWEVKIBqD1WjQbIICCOozkCegeILP3Ly1x/ryNUSVmDgCTpGWKFv5OI5K@6LZEnuKyXZWtajAEhIfnthPPnHkieXNiUqLjLOu8Wgs/PSXifKHdtawdZnYWu3r83n2zsQH4I4bR2b5/iIDzPMe6uxGDiGn3FxjiIPJxsXiwJLDM@4mIXxsozj0/i9n77rmvUNRtc/1ult2h5cuvMZXGOYSSWjYSGvL3dZOUOoplROqRpTHo2duj8)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,c,d)->                  // Method with four double parameters and double return-type
  1737*Math.acos(            //  Return 1737 multiplied with the acos of:
   Math.cos(a-c)             //   the cos of `a` minus `c`,
   +Math.cos(a)*Math.cos(c)  //   plus the cos of `a` multiplied with the cos of `c`
   *(Math.cos(d-b)-1))       //   multiplied with the cos of `d` minus `b` minus 1
```

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"! 88 bytes: `(a,b,c,d)->1737*Math.acos(Math.sin(a)*Math.sin(c)+Math.cos(a)*Math.cos(c)*Math.cos(d-b))`

Comment: "_Premature optimization is the root of all evil_" I guess you're indeed right.. Thanks!

Comment: I've found a shorter formulation: `(a,b,c,d)->1737*Math.acos(Math.cos(a-c)+Math.cos(a)*Math.cos(c)*(Math.cos(d-b)-1))`

Comment: (That formulation isn't shorter in the original Wolfram Language though.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>87 70 69</s> 68 bytes

```ruby
->{extend Math;1737*acos(cos(_1-_3)+cos(_1)*cos(_3)*(cos(_4-_2)-1))}
```

#### Unfortunately, TIO doesn't support `_1` syntax so for TIO, 69 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c,d{extend Math;1737*acos(cos(a-c)+cos(a)*cos(c)*(cos(d-b)-1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nc89D4IwEAbg3V9xwcXWq7YFpGJkdzBxJwzlKzKoRCDRAL8dY1lkIw5v7nLJPcn7bOL3kB8HFmiMMcG0zV51dk/hrOvrQXi2R3XyqFbfaJaQtVkINTdCzT1lMWGCkH4om7oCa9nmIQ0dibBHcDmCjDY3XULbFR0UQI3t@5cTbEEo3kc9MBaAVI61@BXMK4KB/hMcBCbHiHkCt6eC5yEoBDNmCXz6L8YOSs3uYO9ca/gA)

Now using Neil's method, thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

Comment: Using _Neil_'s formula is 17 bytes shorter: [`->a,b,c,d{include Math;1737*acos(cos(a-c)+cos(a)*cos(c)*(cos(d-b)-1))}`](https://tio.run/##nc89D4IwEAbg3V9xwcXWq7Z82IqR3cHEnTiUIpHEDyIwGOC3YyyLbMThzV0uuSd5X3Xy7rN9zyKNCRpMm/xhbnV6gaOurjshPUm1eZaLbzQzZGkXQu2NUHtPWUKYIKTri7oqwZk3WUxj30XYIgQcwT2v7rqAps1byIFaOwxPB1iDULw7d8BYBK7yndmvYF8RLPSf4CMwd4iYJnBvLEiJoBDsmCTw8b8YOig1uYO3CZz@Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>68 66 52</s> 51 bytes

```hs
s=cos;(a!b)c d=1737*acos(s(a-c)+s a*s c*(s(d-b)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYjBCoMwEAXvfsUTetiNhBptsaXkY9YoGLRWsv5/KrnMMLOIrvO25aw@/PRDUo8cMHk39IORa5GS2MCNQowimKsnO7J1zDl5OuLdvVrDVfWVuMPjSHE/cQPVDEp4dEXvwmdb1HH@Aw)

-1 byte thanks to BMO

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23 22</s>  18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-4 bytes thanks to miles (use of `{` and `}` while using [their formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161824/53748).

```
;I}ÆẠP+ÆSP${ÆA×⁽£ġ
```

A dyadic function accepting `[ϕ1, ϕ2,]` on the left and `[λ1, λ2]` on the right in **radians** that returns the result (as floating point).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCgJBDAXQq1jYKUtmMvlJsLK0W7CULW1kLyBiYTNXsFW8hWDjeBG9SGRf/Q77cTxGrDbnVr/PW79oddvPT62u2/V3eb0fn3tE7KhTZmLLJsaKZGU5o840AwVZ3DWh2DDFJErq4Az1Yg5Mk7g4QUyI3Qziwx8)**

---

Mine... (also saved a byte here by using a `{`)

```
,IÆẠCH;ÆẠ{Ḣ+PƊ½ÆṢ×⁽µṣ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/H83Dbw10LnD2swXT1wx2LtAOOdR3aC@TuXHR4@qPGvYe2Pty5@P///9EGeubGxgbGFkYWphbG5maGFiY6CgZ6FuZGZmYmZkamlpbmhmYmFrEghYam5gbmlmbGRmbmliYWlmZmIJUGxiaWBmamFqYGxpYWFmamlrEA)

Comment: Oh interesting, I refreshed the page again and it showed your edit, just clicking new answer to show the change doesn't update to show your edits. the 18 byte alternative was ``;I}ÆẠP+ÆSP${ÆA×⁽£ġ``

Comment: Never understood how to use `{` and `}` they never do what I'd expect. Doesn't that mean I can do the other way in 17?!

Comment: Maybe. `{` and `}` just create a dyad from a monad. A similar view might be `P{ -> ḷP¥`. Might be good to add a *compose* (from J) quick to do something like `x (P+$) y -> (P x) + (P y)` which can save a byte or two in similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB with Mapping Toolbox, 26 bytes

```
@(x)distance(x{:})*9.65*pi
```

Anonymous function that takes the four inputs as a cell array, in the same order as described in the challenge.

Note that this gives exact results (assuming that the Moon radius is 1737 km), because `1737/180` equals `9.65`.

Example run in Matlab R2017b:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>119</s> 103 bytes

This uses degrees.

```python
from math import*
def f(L):a,o,A,O=map(radians,L);return 1737*acos(cos(a-A)+cos(a)*cos(A)*(cos(O-o)-1))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##JY3NCoMwEITvPsWClyRdodEWaYuH3AUfoPSwVINCkw0xPfTprT@HYT6@OUz4pZF9teRA0MCHkkbgjdjrLAdzyBKhO2S52MgOHKURJhc4JpX1gwUrWnknZDTYNY6CiNRP5Gds5SMO6Rs96LqqFb15FluoMPK0g1RbGal23xUsCy3lEuLkk7DieVnfbwjXM0L5Woc/)

Comment: Using _Neil_'s formula is 16 bytes shorter: [`1737*acos(cos(a-A)+cos(a)*cos(A)*(cos(O-o)-1))`](https://tio.run/##JY3NCoMwEITvPsWClyRdodEWaYuH3AUfoPSwVINCkw0xPfTprT@HYT6@OUz4pZF9teRA0MCHkkbgjdjrLAdzyBKhO2S52MgOHKURJhc4JpX1gwUrWnknZDTYNY6CiNRP5Gds5SMO6Rs96LqqFb15FluoMPK0g1RbGal23xUsCy3lEuLkk7DieVnfbwjXM0L5Woc/)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>100</s> <s>88</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

88 → 65 using [*@miles' formula*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon#comment391848_161789)
65 → 64 using [*@Neil's formula*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161789/distance-between-two-points-on-the-moon/161802#comment391978_161802)

```c
#define d(w,x,y,z)1737*acos(cos(w-y)+cos(w)*cos(y)*(cos(z-x)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDRboIwFIbv@xRnGhOK4Ci6gHHufolbdrMrZhZsqTTBslgEYfHVhy3IbNq//f6e09OWuntK27GQNDuxBJ4PcZHO0hd0d1TBRK6tdswSLmQCzKqcs1M7DSbBPLBjmivLjMqt8bRbYNtMNbY7v3HP2CUYt0IWcIiFtMpcMPyLQDfjldFiu@qI5addlsDt/N6jaXyE3YlHxPOHuCoVOszi@6RQlt5zQIkmyblZYw36yhLDwxrePzcbDH0p05SiseR9ymjCYOgjB8qpZ4QY8Y3M8eo/r1q/fX@82mXkbR9J6DnngUnP9cB@z83A847vB/0c9Yu5NZrMPP4lddn7b97KXdClXfiwBHjyAHyk1QfQDizRAlw9m0FQEEAIoBVCRLqYUPPyj/Is3qvWzQ5X)

Comment: I believe you need to add two bytes for the `-lm` compiler flag.

Comment: @O.O.Balance: The presence of the flag is not always required. It depends on how the compiler was installed on the system.

Comment: Alright. Guess this means I can subtract two bytes on this answer of mine: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161452/79343 Thanks.

Comment: @O.O.Balance: Upvoted the answer. I also submitted my own solution.

Comment: Nice. Upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 79 bytes

```
from geopy import*
lambda a,b:distance.great_circle(a,b,radius=1737).kilometers
```

TIO doesn't have geopy.py

Comment: @Nit, my understanding is that it is fair game to use a publicly available library that predates the question.  I thinks it's like using MATLAB's mapping tools, or other languages using a math library.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Complete program. Prompts stdin for {ϕ₁,ϕ₂} and then for {λ₁,λ₂}. Prints to stdout.

Uses the formula r acos(sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ + cos(λ₂ – λ₁) cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂)

```apl
1737×¯2○+/(2○-/⎕)×@2×/1 2∘.○⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM95b@hubH54emH1hs9mt6tra8BonT1H/VN1Tw83cHo8HR9QwWjRx0z9IDCQEGQFq6iR20TgNzD24HihhYG/xXAIIWrSMHESMHUAEgrWCooGHEhxE0NgFIgcSOgFJK4gokC0GIgA0gqKBgiyZibAxFIhQUQIYkbGihYWMBMAgA) (the `r` function converts degrees to radians)

---

`⎕` prompt for {ϕ₁,ϕ₂}

`1 2∘.○` Cartesian trig-function application; {{sin ϕ₁,sin ϕ₂} , {cos ϕ₁,cos ϕ₂}}

`×/` row-wise products; {sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ , cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂}

`(`…`)×@2` at the second element, multiply the following by that:

`⎕` prompt for {λ₁,λ₂}

`-/` difference between those; λ₁ – λ₂

`2○` cosine of that; cos(λ₁ – λ₂)

Now we have {sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ , cos(λ₁ – λ₂) cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂}

`+/` sum; sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ + cos(λ₁ – λ₂) cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂

`¯2○` cosine of that; cos(sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ + cos(λ₁ – λ₂) cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂)

`1737×` multiply r by that; 1737 cos(sin ϕ₁ sin ϕ₂ + cos(λ₁ – λ₂) cos ϕ₁ cos ϕ₂)

---

The function to allow input in degrees is:

```apl
○÷∘180
```

`÷180` argument divided by 180

`○` multiply by π

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 53 bytes

```
=1737*ACOS(COS(A1-C1)+COS(A1)*COS(C1)*(COS(D1-B1)-1))
```

Using @Neil's formula.  Input in Radians.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lobster](http://strlen.com/lobster), 66 bytes

```
def h(a,c,b,d):1737*radians arccos a.sin*b.sin+a.cos*b.cos*cos d-c
```

Uses miles's formula, but input is in degrees. This adds extra step of converting to radians before multiplying by radius.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 88 bytes

*Port of [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161862/78039) answer*

```php
function f($a,$b,$c,$d,$e=cos){return 1737*acos($e($a-$c)+$e($a)*$e($c)*($e($d-$b)-1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpBDoIwFETX7Sn@4i/6axspatCgchYobWBTGoSV8exYuzNhMzN58@IQt3sTU/o12GWcAniBrcJOoVXYK3QPO73oPbtlnQOY6lTJNhGBLnkaLR3yIvkrSzIfvcaOtCGqP5uzwwScecEBGDuXICGOguAI5lqoDG@wAy/FDiz/Tc6o5s1z@wI)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 60 bytes

```
INPUT X,Y,S,T?1737*ACOS(COS(X-S)+COS(X)*COS(S)*(COS(T-Y)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 66 bytes

Clearly the other Wolfram Language golfers only care about *bytes*. *This* program uses the beauty of Mathematica.

```
GeoDistance@@Map[#~GeoPosition~Entity["PlanetaryMoon","Moon"]&,#]&
```

Either I am misusing TIO, or it doesn't work there. This works on my machine, though.